# MySQL says 'SYSDATETIME' does not exist

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select rows from a table where the `date` column value is equal to the current date in Sydney, Australia (UTC+10h). The server is based in Sydney, and so I would like to use `SYSDATETIME()`. This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE DATE(date) = DATE(SYSDATETIME())
```

But this returns the error:

> 1305 - FUNCTION database.SYSDATETIME does not exist

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I used [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? There is no `SYSDATETIME` function in the MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: That documentation is for SQL Server (from Microsoft), not MySQL. There are a lot (lot!!!) of ways they are different. Use the MySQL documentation if you're using a MySQL server.

Comment: @mhutter made an edit to my post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message suggests, there is no such function as `SYSDATETIME` in MySQL. The documentation you are referring to is for Microsoft SQL Server.

The function you are looking for is simply called [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use SYSDATE instead of SYSDATETIME.

The SYSDATE function will return the current date as a 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format.